# A visible box on the right hand side of the document

Tags: pdftex, boxes, tcolorbox

How can I get a small box at the right hand side of the document as in the figure below: [image]

My initial attempt failed:

```
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\textbf{Date:11/12/2018}\\
\textbf{Time: 2:30 PM}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{flushright}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `text width=3cm`, or use `tcbox{}` along with a table:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[text width=3cm]
        \textbf{Date:11/12/2018}\\
        \textbf{Time: 2:30 PM}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{flushright}

\begin{flushright}
\tcbox[left=2pt,right=2pt]{%
    \bfseries
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
        Date: & 11/12/2018 \\
        Time: & 2:30 PM    \\
    \end{tabular}%
}%
\end{flushright}

\end{document}
```